# HTML video tag not showing on source of some websites

Tags: youtube, tags, html5

Why is it that every time I try to view the source of a website that plays HTML 5 video (like YouTube), I don't see the HTML video tag?

For example, on this site: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzPxo7Y6JyA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see the `video` tag if you just load the page source on its own. This is because the `video` DOM element is added to the page dynamically, with JavaScript, and not even persisted in the page source.

Here's the `video` tag in from your example:

[image]

It's inserted through JavaScript inside `<div class="html5-remote-module">` after the video metadata and everything else has been loaded. One reason for not "hard-coding" the `video` tag inside the page is that the link to the video resource has to be present inside the tag (as the `src` attribute), and YouTube distributes the requests to a large number of caching servers rather than pointing to a single resource.

Comment: that's a great explanation. thanks. but where can i find that page source on your example (picture above)?

Comment: In the developer tools of your browser